# Upload DB2 data into an Oracle database - fixing junk data

Tags: oracle, migration, db2, sql-loader

I've been given a DB2 export of data (around 7 GB) with associated DB2 control files.  My goal is to upload all of the data into an Oracle database.  I've almost succeeded in this - I took the route of converting the control files into SQL*Loader CTL files and it has worked for the most part.

However, I have found some of the data files contain terminators and junk data in some of the columns, which is loaded into the database, causing obvious issues with matching on that data. E.g., A column should contain '9930027130', will show length(trim(col)) = 14 : 4 Bytes of junk data.

My question is, what is the best way to eliminate this junk data from the system? I hope theres a simple addition to the CTL file that allows it to replace the junk with spaces - otherwise I can only think of writing a script that analyses the data and replaces nulls/junk with spaces before running SQL*Loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What, exactly, is your definition of "junk"?

If you know that a column should only contain 10 characters of data, for example, you can add a `NULLIF( LENGTH( <<column>> ) > 10 )` to your control file.  If you know that the column should only contain numeric characters (or alphanumerics), you can write a custom data cleansing function (i.e. STRIP_NONNUMERIC) and call that from your control file, i.e.

```
COLUMN_NAME  position(1:14)  CHAR "STRIP_NONNUMERIC(:LAST_NAME)",
```

Depending on your requirements, these cleansing functions and the cleansing logic can get rather complicated.  In data warehouses that are loading and cleansing large amounts of data every night, data is generally moved through a series of staging tables as successive rounds of data cleansing and validation rules are applied rather than trying to load and cleanse all the data in a single step.  A common approach would be, for example, to load all the data into VARCHAR2(4000) columns with no cleansing via SQL*Loader (or external tables).  Then you'd have a separate process move the data to a staging table that has the proper data types NULL-ing out data that couldn't be converted (i.e. non-numeric data in a NUMBER column, impossible dates, etc.).  Another process would come along and move the data to another staging table where you apply domain rules-- things like a social security number has to be 9 digits, a latitude has to be between -90 and 90 degrees, or a state code has to be in the state lookup table.  Depending on the complexity of the validations, you may have more processes that move the data to additional staging tables to apply ever stricter sets of validation rules.

Comment: The junk data was '\0' and random bytes following the real data. I took your advice on the 'Stip_NonNumeric' cleansing function:   **create or replace function StripJunkData( strDat in char )
    return char
is
begin    
    return substr(strDat, 1, instr(strDat, chr(0))-1);
end;**  It appears to work, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

"A column should contain '9930027130', will show length(trim(col)) = 14 : 4 Bytes of junk data. "

Do a SELECT DUMP(col) to determine the strange characters. Then decide whether that are always invalid, valid in some cases or valid but interpreted wrong.